# Adjustment to lazy loading script

Tags: javascript

This script loads background images upon scrolling to them. I'm interested in having the images loaded after the full document is ready instead, but I'm not sure how i'd modify this script to achieve that.

css

```
.hiddenbackground {
background-image: none !important;
}
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var lazyBackgrounds = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenbackground"));

      if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
        let lazyBackgroundObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
          entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
              entry.target.classList.remove("hiddenbackground");
              lazyBackgroundObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
          });
        });

        lazyBackgrounds.forEach(function(lazyBackground) {
          lazyBackgroundObserver.observe(lazyBackground);
        });
      }
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the class `hiddenbackground` is what is the core of this method. Why don't you try removing this class right after your document is loaded?

Comment: In addition to @DanielCheung 's comment: Or simply remove the class from the markup entirely instead of removing it via JS as soon as the page loads?

Comment: @Daniel that's what I'm attempting to do :) not sure how.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevent css

Answer (score -1):

If you need a simple script that removes the CSS class `.hiddenbackground` from all elements that have it as soon as the page loads, you can use something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.hiddenbackground').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove('hiddenbackground');
  });
});
```

**Aside notes**
However, instead of removing_the class as soon as the page loads via JavaScript, why do you ship it in the first place? Instead of using JS to remove a class from the *DOM*, you might (probably) remove it from your *HTML* entirely before it is delivered to a user.

**Alternative "solution"**
Instead of modifying the JS side of things, how about simply deleting the *CSS definition* for `.hiddenbackground`?

```
.hiddenbackground {
  /* background-image: none !important; */
}
```

Or just delete it entirely.

Comment: I'm extremely confused. I set the class so that upon initial paint, the images don't load. If I don't include the class on the divs, the images load, which is the problem. Removing the class or the css declaration is counter to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @JasonHoward In that case, I don't understand your question. You stated that you want to remove the class _on page load_, right ("I'm interested in having the images loaded after the full document is ready instead")? Also, you said in a comment it's what you where "attempting to do, [but] not sure how". That's what my script does, it waits for the 'load' event of the document and removes the class from all elements that have it so the images do load _after_ the document is ready. Did I miss something?